# mdx first value of a period

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have a cube with a 'sales' measure, where we have the amount of sold units each day. We have a time dimension with 'Year > week > day'.

I need to have the sales for the first and the last day in a period with non empty sales for a calculated field. I tried with OPENINGPERIOD and CLOSINGPERIOD but they return for a week period just Monday and Sunday... the problem is that sometimes Monday is holiday and Sunday is always holiday and I get empty data (we have no sales on holidays)... Here is my example for last day of a period:

```
WITH
  MEMBER 
   [Measures].[sales end] AS 
      '((CLOSINGPERIOD([Time.Weeks].[Day],[Time.Weeks].CurrentMember)
       , [Measures].[sales]))'
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[sales], [Measures].[sales end]} ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY 
   ({[Time.Weeks].[Week].Members}) ON ROWS 
FROM [cubSales]
```

I need to get the last day with non empty sales in that period... it should be Friday, but if Friday is holiday, it should be Thursday... I mean the last day for the week with a value for the measure sales..

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution could be to just omit holiday days from your time dimension.

Comment: thanks! this is not possible because we have several stores and a day can be holiday for only a subset but not for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Mondrian has no concept of holidays. I would implement my own MDX function with a built-in list of holidays. It's a flexible approach which can be extended to support different holidays from different countries.

Comment: Hi Luc, what I am really looking for is the first and last day of a period with a not null value for the sales measure, so we could check holiday calendar or just look for that not null value. 

I think you are talking about customize the function CLOSINGPERIOD... for that I need to have the [Time.Weeks].CurrentMember and the sales measure... but I have no idea how to access the measure values for that days...

Could you give me some initial tips please??

Answer (score 0):

Tested on our cube and seems to work ok (just doesn't say anything about holidays!)

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[sales]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Generate
    (
      [Time.Weeks].MEMBERS
     ,Tail
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [Time.Weeks].CurrentMember * [Time.Weeks].[Day].MEMBERS //<<I think .members is generally default but should do the same thing if we are explicit
         ,[Measures].[sales]
        )
      )
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [cubSales];
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I'm using Pentaho 5.1 and when I try to execute your query in JPivot I get: _Mondrian Error:No function matches signature '<Member> * <Level>'_. 

Are you using Pentaho 5.1 also?? What could be the problem?

Comment: not sure - I've tested the above against Adventure Works in SQL-Server Management Studio so it is valid `MDX`. I'm guessing you need to translate this into Mondrian's dialect. We use Pyramid but I'm not involved in it's particular flavour of MDX: currently I use `standard MDX` in SQL stored procedures using the T-SQL function `OPENQUERY`. Although try just adding `.members` after `[Day]` - I have edited answer...